# Fixed field of C(t) subfield

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

> $$ \sigma:t \rightarrow \frac{t+i}{t-i} $$
>
> $$ \tau  :t \rightarrow \frac{it-i}{t+1} $$
>
> We assume that group $G$ is generated by $\sigma$, $\tau$.
>
> Prove that: $G$ is isomorphic with the alternating group $A_4$.
> Moreover, compute the fixed field of $G$.

$\sigma^3=1$ and $\tau^3=1$ and $\sigma\tau\sigma\tau=1$  by Todd-Coxeter Algorithm I can prove it $A_4$

By find the track of t
$\{t,-t, \frac{1}{t}, -\frac{1}{t}, \frac{t+i}{t-i},\frac{t-i}{t+i}, -\frac{t+i}{t-i},-\frac{t-i}{t+i}, i\frac{t+1}{t-1},i\frac{t-1}{t+1},-i\frac{t+1}{t-1},-i\frac{t-1}{t+1}\}$

After very long computation and I am not sure whether it right.
$[x^4-(t^2+\frac{1}{t^2})x^2+1][x^4+2(\frac{t^4+6t^2+1}{(t^2-1)^2})x^2+1][x^4-2(\frac{t^4-6t^2+1}{(t^2+1)^2})x^2+1]$
I still cannot find out the fixed field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Promoting the comments to an alternative argument for the fact that the group $G=\langle \sigma,\tau\rangle\simeq A_4$:

- $z_1=(1+i)(1-\sqrt3)/2$ is a fixed point of $\sigma$. If we declare $z_2=\tau(z_1)$, $z_3=\sigma(z_2)=-z_1$ and $z_4=\sigma(z_3)=-z_2$, then $z_4$ is a fixed point of $\tau$, and both $\sigma$ and $\tau$ act on the set $X=\{z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4\}$ as 3-cycles. More precisely as $(234)$ and $(123)$ (on the subscripts).
- From this action we get a homomorphism $\phi:G\to Sym(X)$. As the generators act via 3-cycles the image only consists of even permutations of $X$. It is well known and easy to verify that any two 3-cycles with distinct fixed points of $A_4$ generate all of $A_4$. So $\phi:G\to A_4$ is surjective.
- Any Möbius transformation with more than two fixed points is necessarily the identity. But the elements in the kernel of $\phi$ have at least four fixed points. Thus we can conclude that $\phi$ is also injective.

---

On with the task of identifying the fixed field. Here I confess to using Mathematica to speed up the processing of these rational functions as well as to diminish the chance of errors. The list of the twelve elements of $G$ was already figured out by the OP, so I simply expanded the polynomial
$$
m(x)=\prod_{\alpha\in G}(x-\alpha(t))
$$
that we expect to be the minimal polynomial of $t$ over the fixed field $K$.

Upon inspection we see that the coefficients of $m(x)$ can be written in terms of the rational function
$$
\begin{aligned}
w&=\frac{(t^2-2 t-1) (t^2+2 t-1) (t^4+1)
   (t^4+6 t^2+1)}{t^2(t^4-1)^2}\\
&=\frac{t^{12}-33t^8-33t^4+1}{t^{10}-2t^6+t^2},
\end{aligned}
$$
and reads
$$
m(x)=x^{12}-wx^{10}-33x^8+2wx^6-33x^4-wx^2+1.
$$
Using the factorizations of the numerator and the denominator of $w$ should make it easier to verify that $w$ is, indeed, in the fixed field of $G$. The details are a bit taxing though, so as an alternative we can use the observation that essentially $w$ is the sum of squares of the orbit of $t$:
$$2w=\sum_{\alpha\in G}\alpha(t)^2.$$

Anyway, the rest is easy. The coefficients of $m(x)$ are in the subfield $L=\Bbb{C}(w)\subseteq K$. Furthermore, $t$ is a zero of a degree $12$ polynomial with coefficients in $L$, so $[\Bbb{C}(t):L]=[L(t):L]\le 12$. On the other hand, Galois theory together with the tower law tells us that
$$
[\Bbb{C}(t):K]=|G|=12=[\Bbb{C}(t):L]/[K:L]\le 12/[K:L].
$$
The only possibility is thus that we have equalities $K=L$ and $[\Bbb{C}(t):L]=12$. A consequence of this is that $m(x)$ must be the minimal polynomial of $t$ over $K=L$.

---

We knew in advance that we must have $K=\Bbb{C}(f)$ for some element $f\in\Bbb{C}(t)$. By [Lüroth's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%BCroth%27s_theorem) all the intermediate fields between $\Bbb{C}$ and $\Bbb{C}(t)$ are of that form.

Comment: A possibly useful observation is that $\tau(t)=i\sigma(-it)$. This could help when checking that $w$ is invariant under both $\sigma$ and $\tau$. Anyway, the two transformations are conjugate in a bigger group, and there have the same order as well as other mapping properties.

Comment: Also, if you just check that $w$ is an invariant, then you get the polynomial $m(x)$ without that horrid expansion simply by clearing the denomimator from the equation defining $w$. Voila, a degree $12$ equation for $t$ with coefficients in $w$.

Comment: This alternative way could reduce much calculation and reduce the mistake, but
I have little different calculation of $w=\frac{(t^4+1)(t^4-1)^2}{t^2(t^4-1)^2}-2\frac{t^2(t^4+6t+1)(t^2+1)}{t^2(t^4-1)^2}+2\frac{t^2(t^4-6t+1)(t^2-1)}{t^2(t^4-1)^2}$

Comment: @WumingLiu I just observed that
$$2w=\sum_{\alpha\in G}\alpha(t)^2.$$ This matches with Vieta relations for the coefficient of $x^{10}$.